# Customization of activity feed for new colleagues

Tags: my-site, activity-feed, newsfeed

Is it possible to customize the activity feed to the MySite NewsFeed when a new colleague is added? For example, change the domain\userid text to display the DisplayName instead?

Thanks,
Tom